# I need to extract the numbers from a string

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Using `bash` I'm trying to extract only the numbers before a string.

For example:

```
7prob542334
```

Expected output :

```
7
```

But I run into an error when I have

```
27prob542334
```

Expected output :

```
27
```

instead I get `2`

This the code I have so far :

```
max=$(ls -LR $ARCHIVE | grep  ^prob | sed 's/_.*//' | uniq -c | sort -rn | tr -d ' '| head -n1 | head -c1)
```

Archive is the path to a directory with sub-directories that store files like `prob542334_05`. I removed the underscore and sorted the file based on it's occurrence. Then I try extracting just the occurrence number like `"7"` or `"27"`

Comment: plenty of other problem with your code such as [ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), using `uniq` on possibly unsorted input, etc... good idea to all quote pattern.. for ex `grep '^prob'`

Comment: if you can describe what is your complete question, you can avoid [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)... see also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 3):

With `bash` parameter expansion:

```
${var%%[[:alpha:]]*}
```

- We are greedily removing substring from right (`%%`), from end to the first alphabetic (`[[:alpha:]]*`) character (from left).

**Example:**

```
$ var='7prob542334'

$ echo "${var%%[[:alpha:]]*}"
7

$ var='27prob542334'

$ echo "${var%%[[:alpha:]]*}"
27
```

Comment: More generally we can write:  `${var%%[^[:digit:]]*}` --  remove the first *non-digit* and all subsequent characters

Answer (score 3):

Using `bash`'s own `regex` matching, with `([[:digit:]]+)(.*)`

```
$ string="7prob542334"
$ [[ $string =~ ([[:digit:]]+)(.*) ]] && num=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
$ printf "%s\n" "$num"
7

$ string="27prob542334"
$ [[ $string =~ ([[:digit:]]+)(.*) ]] && num=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
$ printf "%s\n" "$num"
27
```

Comment: You don't need to capture the rest of the string: `[[ $string =~ ^([[:digit:]]+).* ]]`

Answer (score 2):

```
echo 127prob542334 |grep -o  '^[0-9]*'
127

echo 17prob542334 |grep -oP  '^\d*'
17
```

Answer (score 2):

```
echo 127prob542334 | grep -o -E '[0-9]+' | head -1 | sed -e 's/^0\+//'
```

OR

```
echo 127prob542334 | grep -o '^[0-9]*'
```

Comment: Sorry I have missed quotes

Answer (score 1):

In awk:

```
$ echo 127prob542334|awk 'sub(/[^0-9].*/,"") || 1'
127
```

Bash:

```
$ i=127prob542334
$ echo ${i%%[^0-9]*}
127
```

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`, you can make use of the `printf` command which will only take the decimal part of the string given in argument:

```
echo "127prob542334" | awk '{printf "%d\n",$1}'
```

Answer (score 1):

If Perl is an option:

`echo 27prob542334 | perl -lne 'print $1 if /^(\d+)/'`

outputs:

`27`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '27prob542334' |grep -Po '^\d+'
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.